# Can't style my login form to be at the center with a beautiful card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I'm trying to make a login form like [This one](https://www.positronx.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/react-login-ui-6748-01.png) using `Bootstrap5`, but i can't, is anybody who can help me to make a login form  like the one i mentioned here ? Actually I'm begineer in bootstrap and css.

my template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <h5>{{ message }}</h5>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="text-primary">Enter Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                </div>
                
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="text-primary ">Enter Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                </div>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few additional classes from their library and it looks like so. There is a class referenced called `font-weight-bold` that wasn't working, so I added that as CSS. I guess it depends on which version bootstrap you are using.

```css
.container {
  background: #1D8FF9;
  padding: 10rem 0;
}
.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.btn-block {
  display: block!important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <h5>{{ message }}</h5>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    </div>
</div>-->

<div class="container p-10">
    <div class="form-container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="card p-5">
              <h2 class="text-center">Sign In</h2>
              <br>
              <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                  <!--{% csrf_token %}-->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="text-primary text-dark font-weight-bold">Enter Username</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter Email">
                  </div>

                  <br>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="text-primary text-dark font-weight-bold">Enter Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                  </div>
                                    <br>
                  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember Me</label>
  </div>
                  <br>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
              </form>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap version 5, The latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to get as close to the example you have shown, but I would recommend you to recreate this purely using CSS first, especially get a good working knowledge of CSS Grid and Flexbox, later when you jump into Bootstrap you will understand it much faster.

```css
body {
  background: #f5f6f9;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 1px 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center min-vh-100">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="card py-4 px-3">
        <h3 class="text-center fw-bold">Sign In</h1>
          <div class="mt-3">
            <form action="" method="post">
              <div class="col-xl-12">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Password</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-check mb-3">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary w-100">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                  <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)